# Upper bound on the expectation $E[(X-t)^+]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a random variable with $E[X]=0$ and $E[X^2]=1$ that satisfies
>   \begin{equation}
>   |F_X(x) - \Phi(x)| \leq \alpha, \qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R},
> \end{equation}
>   where $F_X(\cdot)$ is the cdf and $\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-y^2/2} \mathrm{d}y$.
>
> I am looking for an upper bound on $E[ (X-t)^+]$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $t$.

- Neglecting the constraint $|F_X(x) - \Phi(x)| \leq \alpha$, an upper bound can be found as following using Jensen's inequality
  \begin{align}
  E[t-X + 2 (X-t)^+]^2 = E[|X-t|]^2\leq E[(X-t)^2] = 1 + t^2
  \end{align}
  from which I obtain
  \begin{align}
  E[(X-t)^+] \leq \frac{1}{2}\left( \sqrt{1 + t^2} -t\right).
  \end{align}
- However, when $\alpha$ is small, $X$ is approximately Gaussian distributed, and hence I expect $E[(X-t)^+]$ to be bounded as
  \begin{align}
   E[(X-t)^+] \leq \int_{t}^{\infty} \phi(x) (x-t) \mathrm{d}x + \epsilon(\alpha),
  \end{align}
  where $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} $. Numerical simulations suggests that $\epsilon(\cdot)$ can be chosen as $\epsilon(x)=c \cdot x$ for some positive constant $c$.
- I have attempted to upper bound $E[(X-t)^+]$ in terms of the cdf as following
  \begin{align}
  E[(X-t)^+] = \int_{t}^{\infty} (1-F_X(x))\mathrm{d}x \leq \int_{t}^{\infty} (1-\Phi(x)+\alpha )\mathrm{d}x = \int_{t}^{\infty} \phi(x) (x-t) \mathrm{d}x + \int_t^\infty \alpha \mathrm{d}x,
  \end{align}
  but then the last integral is divergent which suggests that the second moment must be used.